# (node:5151) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js

I have the following async function that successfully runs on every result returned by the "Quote.insertMany" mongoose method.   However, once I run the function I get a "SAVED" output for each one followed by the following error for each one of them:

```
SAVED
SAVED
...
SAVED
(node:5151) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5151) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended
...
Closing connection
```

What's wrong with the function below?  i.e. how can I handle these rejections:

```js
(async function(){
    db.connect();
    await Quote.insertMany(quotes).
    then(results => {
        
        return Promise.all((results).map(function(quote) {

            return Author.findOne({id: quote.authorid}, function(err, author){

                if (err){
                    return next(err);
                }

                if(author != null){
                    try{
                        author.quotes.push(quote._id);
                        author.save();              
                        console.log("SAVED");
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        return next(e);
                    }
                }
            })
        }))
    }).
    catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });

    console.log("Closing connection");
    db.close();
    
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This was simple.  I didn't realize "save()" was returning a promise.

Fix:

```
author.save().then().catch(e => {                        
    console.log(e);
});
```